# onSchedule eventType for Firebase Extension?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, firebase-extensions

I decided to upgrade my extension to use 2nd generation Cloud Functions. I changed my cloud function from `pubsub.schedule` to `onSchedule`.

In extensions.yaml I have to define `resources.properties.eventTrigger.eventType`. However I am not able to find any hints in the documentation: https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/publishers/functions#scheduled

The resources section in my extensions.yaml file.

```
resources:
  - name: backupauthusers
    type: firebaseextensions.v1beta.v2function
    description: >-
      Scheduled function that will backup Authentication users to Google Cloud Storage bucket.
    properties:
      eventTrigger:
        eventType: <What event type?>
      buildConfig:
        runtime: nodejs18
```

Some eventTypes I have attempted:

- google.pubsub.topic.publish
- google.cloud.pubsub.topic.publish

They have resulted in deployment errors, I guess the type is invalid:

Extensions deploy had errors:

- create backup-firebase-auth
  ; RESOURCE_ERROR at /deployments/firebase-ext-backup-firebase-auth/resources/backupauthusers: {"ResourceType":"gcp-types/cloudfunctions-v2beta:projects.locations.functions","ResourceErrorCode":"400","ResourceErrorMessage":{"code":400,"message":"Validation failed for trigger projects/test-backup-firebase-auth/locations/asia-southeast1/triggers/ext-backup-firebase-auth-backupauthusers-424196: The request was invalid: invalid value for attribute 'type' in trigger.event_filters: "name:\"projects/test-backup-firebase-auth/locations/asia-southeast1/triggers/ext-backup-firebase-auth-backupauthusers-424196\"  event_filters:{attribute:\"type\"  value:\"google.pubsub.topic.publish\"}  service_account:\"485153738786-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com\"  destination:{cloud_function:\"gcf-encoded|projects/test-backup-firebase-auth/locations/asia-southeast1/functions/ext-backup-firebase-auth-backupauthusers|invalid\"}  labels:{key:\"goog-managed-by\"  value:\"cloudfunctions\"}"","status":"INVALID_ARGUMENT","statusMessage":"Bad Request","requestPath":"https://cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/v2beta/projects/test-backup-firebase-auth/locations/asia-southeast1/functions","httpMethod":"POST"}}

Error: Extensions deployment failed.

Comment: Schedule triggers use `scheduleTrigger` instead of an `eventTrigger`, so the configuration is likely structured like the [exported metadata](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-functions/blob/3e7a4b77967e46a067712445c499c5df005b8e31/src/runtime/manifest.ts#L84-L98). Try inspecting the object returned by `onSchedule` for clues.

Comment: @samthecodingman hey sam, thanks for your reply. As per my understanding scheduleTrigger is only for 1st generation cloud functions, there is no such field for 2nd generation cloud functions. https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/reference/extension-yaml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Received confirmation from Firebase team that scheduled functions are currently not available in 2nd generation cloud functions as of now.

Answer (score 1):

Firebase Extensions does not currently support 2nd generation Cloud Functions.

Cloud tasks could be an alternative in the meantime, but this would depend on your requirements and reasoning for upgrading to 2nd gen:

```
    export const myFunction = functions.tasks.taskQueue({
      ...config
    })
```

Source: https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/task-functions?gen=1st#writing_task_queue_functions

Comment: Hey Darren, thanks for your reply. Do you mean Firebase extensions do not support 2nd generation scheduled functions or 2nd generation functions as a whole? The documentation states Firebase Extensions do support 2nd gen functions.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/extensions/publishers/functions#scheduled

Comment: The documentation now seems to suggest some but not all, as an example it is my understanding that any v2beta or v1beta.v2function would not yet be supported.

See: `However, Firebase Extensions currently have some restrictions on which generation of cloud function you can use with certain trigger types. For this reason, many extensions include a mix of 1st and 2nd generation functions.`.

EventArc for example can be used with functionsv2.eventarc. For now I guess it could be trial and error based ont he docs. But maybe if there is an issue then this may not be yet available!

Comment: Yea, I was hoping the documentation would be clearer in what were the restrictions as well as which trigger types. Thanks for the help!